# homeomorphism on the sphere

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems

I want to prove that for all homeomorphism (or diffeo) $g:S^2\to S^2$ on the sphere, it doesn't exists $\lambda\in (0,1)$ with
$$d(g^n(x),g^n(y))\leq \lambda^nd(x,y)$$
for every pair of points $x,y\in S^2$ and $n>0$. Here the distance $d(x,y)$ is the the infimum of the lengths of differentiable curves in $S^2$ connecting the two points.

I know that if the above relation holds for some $\lambda\in (0,1)$, then every two points will be iteratively brought closer to each other. So, every open set will be condenced to compact sets or points when $n\to \infty$. This should mean that $f$ is not even bijective, but I don't know how to formalize it properly. Any help?

Maybe there is also an alternative proof by the Brouwer fixed point but I'm not sure either.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Such an homeomorphism has a fixed point $x$, (for every $z$, $g^n(z)$ is Cauchy)  if $y$ is another point, $d(x,g(x))< d(x,y)\leq 1$ implies that $g$ is not surjective. Contradiction.